# Apply VBA Code on specific cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an audit trail to record changes effected on Sheet One and record them on Sheet 2. The code works fine however, I would like to restrict the code to run only on specific cells i.e. (A1:L100). The reason is that I have some workings from column M onwards and so I do not want to record any movements in these workings. Any suggestion on what to add/amend to the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Public dArr As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim nArr As Variant
Dim auditRecord As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
nArr = Me.UsedRange
 'Look for changes to the used range
For i = 1 To UBound(dArr, 2)
    For j = 1 To UBound(dArr, 1)
        If nArr(j, i) <> dArr(j, i) Then
            'write to range
            If Not Write_Change(dArr(j, i), nArr(j, i), Me.Cells(j, i).Address) Then
                MsgBox "The change was not recorded.", vbInformation
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Erase nArr, dArr
dArr = Me.UsedRange
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Dim Cell As Range
Dim oldValue As Variant

For Each Cell In target
    On Error Resume Next
    oldValue = vbNullString
    oldValue = dArr(Cell.Row, Cell.Column)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oldValue <> Cell.Value Then
        If Not Write_Change(oldValue, Cell.Value, Cell.Address) Then
            MsgBox "The change was not recorded.", vbInformation
        End If
    End If
Next Cell

On Error Resume Next
Erase dArr
On Error GoTo 0

dArr = Me.UsedRange
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
dArr = Me.UsedRange
End Sub

Public Function Write_Change(oldValue, newValue, cellAddress As String) As     Boolean
Dim auditRecord As Range
On Error GoTo errHandler
Set auditRecord = Sheets("ChangeHistory").Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1, 0)
With auditRecord
    .Value = cellAddress 'Address of change
    .Offset(0, 1).Value = newValue 'new value
    .Offset(0, 2).Value = oldValue 'previous value
    .Offset(0, 3).NumberFormat = "dd mm yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    .Offset(0, 3).Value = Now 'time of change
    .Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.UserName 'user who made change
    .Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.Range("D" & Split(cellAddress, "$")(2)).Value
End With
Write_Change = True
Exit Function
errHandler:
Write_Change = False
Debug.Print "Error number: " & Err.Number
Debug.Print "Error descr: " & Err.Description
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Write_Change` you can test your `cellAddress` to see if it's something you want to write about. For instance, if you only wanted to capture changed in `A1:F50` you could write:

```
If Not(Intersect(Me.Range(cellAddress), me.Range("A1:F50")) IS NOTHING) Then
    Write_Change = False
    Exit Function
End If
```

Or something along those lines. If your range of acceptable cells is made up of multiple areas, you can check out the `UNION` function to stitch them into a single range that you can test with that `IF Not(Intersect() Is Nothing))` logic.